# How do you apply the odd selector after you've selected based upon attribute value?

Tags: jquery

Hi I'm trying to select the odd number of rows that do not inlcude a specific attribute.  I can select odd, and i can select based on attribute value, but how to you select on both?

```
$("#tableId tr [data-ignoreAlternateRowCss!=true]:odd").addClass("altGridRow");
```

Comment: jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pddFr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `:odd` selector first and then apply the attribute selector. Try this.

```
$("#test tr:odd[data-ignorealternaterowcss!='true']").addClass("altGridRow");​
```

You can also use jQuery `filter()` which reduces the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

```
$("#test tr:odd").filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('ignorealternaterowcss') != true; 
}).addClass("altGridRow");​
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pddFr/4/)**

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: Still not working.  Tried both methods w/o success.  Cleaned out some excess html.  Both of your solutions are here:
http://jsfiddle.net/pddFr/6/

Comment: If you check my demo it works fine. Make sure your html is correct.

Comment: In your fiddle you have missed to include the jQuery library and also both the odd rows `data-ignorealertnaterowcss` is true so selector will not select any rows. Take a look I fixed your fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/pddFr/7/

Comment: Ugg, sorry.  Newish to jsFiddle.  Works great - thanks for the help!